# In unity, how to force an animation to replay itself even if it is not finished playing

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm making a little fps project in Unity3D and would like to implement a good and responsive hitmarker system. I tried Coroutine and Animation.

I'm currently doing it through animation but i can't make it so the animation would replay itself even if it's not done playing.
Causing the issue of : If i click too fast the second hit will not show an hitmaker.

I would just need maybe an "Animation.ForcePlay" or something like that.

Any help is very appreciated :D
Thanks in advance !

This is my gun/shooting script

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class Gun : MonoBehaviour
{

    public float damageBody = 10f;
    public float damageHead = 20f;
    public float range = 100f;

    public Camera fpsCam;

    // Effect Video and Sound
    public ParticleSystem muzzleFlash;
    public GameObject impactEffect;
    public AudioSource gunShot;
    public AudioSource hitMarkerBodySound;
    public AudioSource hitMarkerHeadSound;

    public float showtime;
    public GameObject hitMarkerBody;
    public GameObject hitMarkerHead;

    public GameObject CanvasCrosshair;
    public Animation anim;

    void Start()
    {
        anim = CanvasCrosshair.GetComponent<Animation>();
    }

    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetButtonDown("Fire1"))
        {
            Shoot();
        }
    }

    void Shoot()
    {
        muzzleFlash.Play();
        gunShot.Play(0);

        RaycastHit hit;
        if (Physics.Raycast(fpsCam.transform.position, fpsCam.transform.forward, out hit, range))
        {
            Debug.Log(hit.transform);
            TargetBody targetBody = hit.transform.GetComponent<TargetBody>();
            TargetHead targetHead = hit.transform.GetComponent<TargetHead>();

            if (targetBody != null)
            {   
                targetBody.TakeDamageBody(damageBody);
                hitMarkerBodySound.Play(1);
                // StopCoroutine(HitMarkerBodyShow());
                // hitMarkerBody.SetActive(true);
                // StartCoroutine(HitMarkerBodyShow());
                anim.Play("HitMarkerBodyAnim");
            } else if (targetHead != null)
            {
                targetHead.TakeDamageHead(damageHead);
                hitMarkerHeadSound.Play(2);
            }

            Instantiate(impactEffect, hit.point, Quaternion.LookRotation(hit.normal));
        }
    }

    // IEnumerator HitMarkerBodyShow()
    // {
    //     yield return new WaitForSeconds(showtime);
    //     hitMarkerBody.SetActive(false);
    // }
}
```

The canvasCrosshair is the canvas where i display both my crosshair and hitmarker.
It has an animation component on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you read carefully in [`Animation.Play`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Animation.Play.html) it states

> If the specified animation is already playing then other animations will be stopped but the animation will **not rewind to the beginning**.

Afaik you can force a restart of the clip using [`Animation.Rewind`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Animation.Rewind.html) before your `Play` line

```
anim.Rewind("HitMarkerBodyAnim");
anim.Play("HitMarkerBodyAnim");
```

or you could probably even check and do

```
if(anim.IsPlaying("HitMarkerBodyAnim"))
{
    anim.Rewind("HitMarkerBodyAnim");
}
else
{
    anim.Play("HitMarkerBodyAnim");
}
```

not sure what the differences in performance would be